# Properly getting Electron cookies (asynchronous)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, cookies, electron

I think I have a *good* understanding of what *asynchronous* means in JavaScript.
I am well aware that I can use something like *callback functions* to modify variables from asynchronous functions.

*I am not, however, sure how to use this with the cookies in Electron.*
What I mean is, I can get the cookie by doing:

```
function getCookie( name ) {

    // 'ses' refers to 'mainWindow.webContents.session'
    ses.cookies.get({name: name}, function(err, cookie) {
        if ( err ) throw err;
        console.log(cookie[0].value);
    });

}
```

I can easily output the cookie to the console. However, since this is asynchronous, I don't know how to set any variables.

- *How can I achieve this? How do I set a variable form inside the 'cookies.get' method, since I can not use callbacks?*

Comment: Why can you not use callbacks?

Comment: The function (err, cookie) can not have another parameter, at least when I tried it.

Comment: But your getCookie() can, can't it?

Comment: Ah... There we go. I knew I was missing something. Thank you very much! If you want, you can post an answer and I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the use of a global variable:

```
var cookieLoaded = false;
function getCookie( name ) {
    // 'ses' refers to 'mainWindow.webContents.session'
    ses.cookies.get({name: name}, function(err, cookie) {
        if ( err ) throw err;
        console.log(cookie[0].value);
        cookieLoaded = true;
    });
}

//in other parts of the code...
//you probably want this to be in events, like click handlers, etc.

if (cookieLoaded) {
  //DO STUFF
} else {
  alert('You are not authenticated');
  //or, disable buttons, etc.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but that's the thing. *cookieLoaded* doesn't change since this is asynchronous. That's the reason I made this post :) I did manage to fix it by following Luca Kiebel's advice :) Thanks anyway!